I'm on a linux box, trying to use pexpect.spawn to remote login to other linux boxes. But it looks like spawn and run disabled
I'm trying to use pexpect.spawn in a python script, but read on this forum that developers disabled spawn and run in pexpect module. I'm not using window, I'm trying to login from a linux box to other linux boxes to run commands. What other option available that can do same as pexpect.spawn?
AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'spawn'
If I'm not using windows, why pexpect.spawn is erroring out?
AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'spawn'

your script is named pexpect.py?

I successfully use pexpect.spawn under Fedora 40. This to echo previous comment.
